# TypeScript using super on static get in mixin

Tags: typescript, inheritance, mixins, super

I have a situation where I want to use the return value a of getter that is present on the superclass in a mixin.

I have problems with the type information. It seems that the superclass does not have the static getter. I have created [an example in the typescript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAEBiD29oG8CwAoaWIBcw4EthoBzAUx2gCMwAnACgEoUMs3paKBXWgO2gCsAblZYAvhgnoMZAB4AHeLUo4AnvLLQA4mV5laRAMLxeuWl2A4lAHgAqAPmgBeaHoDu0egDofdEhAAuaDBeVQBtAF1mJ0dbEWl0YBNcOEQAWQJZAn4XO2g5HF0AExgdPQNgY1Mcc0sbBHh7e3oILg1aQ3AoINtoxzRMLE4cHn5QSBgC4phW9s6JlkH2XHwiUgpqOiZF9l2k6uglAhJssBBnaFn9LxpaeN32YdHDgxPeM%20gAamgARnvdqRsKRSIA).

My question is, how do I fix this type information?